# Toggle vuetify icon if button is clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a div where I want to toggle the icon if the button is clicked:

```
<div>
  <v-btn
    v-if="play"
    icon
    @click="true"
  >
    <v-icon>mdi-volume-off</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn
    v-else
    icon
    @click="false"
  >
    <v-icon>mdi-volume-high</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</div>
```

In my data I have play set to false:

```
  data () {
    play: false
  }
```

What am I missing to toggle the icons on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like that:

```html
<div>
  <v-btn
    icon
    @click="toggleIsPlaying"
  >
    <v-icon v-if="isPlaying">mdi-volume-off</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-else>mdi-volume-high</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</div>
```

plus `data()` should return a value of all your data:

```js
data () {
   return {
     isPlaying: false
   }
},

methods: {
   toggleIsPlaying() {
      this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
   }
}
```

when you do `@click="true"` it doesn't do anything, you need to call a method of do some sort of action when the button is click, like changing `isPlayign` data for example.